# How to install the Nativescript OCR module

Tags: android, tesseract, nativescript

Has anyone had any luck getting the OCR module (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-ocr) running?

I have installed it and get the following error:

`Error in ocr.scan: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tesseract' of undefined`

I have installed tesseract via apt (which I did not think would help and didn't).

I have run tns build android.

I am guessing that I need the tesseract libs to be added to my project. I can see that the module has a include.gradle file which requires the github repo every source of documentation I have read refences, but I cannot seem to get the libs installed.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

tesseract ocr needs a language to detect the text (with the extension *.traineddata).

In [this url](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata) you can download it.

Then, follow the instructions of nativescript ocr plugin and create a folder (app/tesseract/tessdata/) and add these files inside.

Finally, If you want to change the lenguage, I have gone to the plugin inside of node_modules and change the "eng" word for other language like "esp", but I think, there will be a better solution for this.